# .htaccess убрать повторяющиеся слэши и добавить слешь вконце URL

Tags: .htaccess

Есть **.htaccess** следующего содержания:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.svn/ - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mySite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myCite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mySite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*?).mySite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.mySite.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule !(.*).(txt|css|jpg|gif|png|ico|js|htc)$ /index.php [L]
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mySite.com/404.html
```

**Задача:**

    1. Убрать все повторяющиеся слеши;
    2. 301 редирект со страниц без слеша на слеш.

т.е. адреса: `www.mySite.com//category/`,`www.mySite.com//category`,`www.mySite.com/category` 301 редирект на `www.mySite.com/category/`

Но, есть одно НО - AJAX-запросы мы не обрабатываем.

Пробовал следующие строки, вставлял между 4 и 6 строками:

```
# Check whether the repeated slashes (//) more than two times.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
# Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Но, происходит очень много перенаправлений и при большой посещаемости сервер "падает".

Как можно это обработать одним правилом или лучше это делать в PHP-коде?

P.S.: предлагайте решение задачи, а не вопросы: "А как так получилось?"

Comment: Откуда у вас берутся двойные (и больше) слеши в адресах?

Comment: Нужно решение задачи, а не наводящие вопросы. Есть требование SEO и их нужно реализовать. Например, могут взяться, если пользователь вручную прописал URL. Конечно, логично показать ошибку 404. Но, если у Вас крупный интернет магазин, то Вам выгодней "срезать" лишний слешь и перенаправить на страницу с товаром, т.к. Вы рискуете потерять пользователя.